# Redux Thunk trying to return a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have the following actionCreator in Redux:

```
export function updateValuesRouting(values, routingID ){
    const url = `${ROOT_ROUTINGS_URL}/${routingID}/editing/meta`;
    console.log("routing url:: ",url, values);
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: UPDATE_VALUE_ROUTING_LOADING, isLoaded: false});
        return axios.put(url, values)
            .then(({data}) => {
            console.log("returned values from updateValuesRouting:",data);
                dispatch({type: UPDATE_VALUE_ROUTING, data, isLoaded:true})
                return Promise.resolve();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch(alertMessage("danger", `${routingID} has not updated values. ${err}`));
                dispatch({type: UPDATE_VALUE_ROUTING_FAILURE, isLoaded: true})
            })
    }
}
```

What I want to do with the return on the axios call is to have a promise returned, so I know the action has completed, and I can make another call with it. However, in another actioncreator I called:

```
dispatch(updateValuesRouting(values, routingID).then(//put some other code here))
```

And I was unable to reach it, said:

> Uncaught TypeError: updateValuesRouting(...).then is not a function

I am pretty sure this is a syntax error on my part. I thought i only needed to have that return in front of axios call to get the promise to pass, but I am missing something else I think. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `updateValuesRouting` returns a function that is not the axios call; it returns a call taking `dispatch`. It's not a syntax error, it's a programming error.

Comment: so how can I rewrite this so I can have the loading called and have it return the promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per `thunk` [document](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition)

> Any return value from the inner function will be available as the
>   return value of dispatch itself

You are returning promise from your `updateValuesRouting`, so you can wait till the response arrive using a bit change how you are using `then`, You need to change

```
dispatch(updateValuesRouting(values, routingID).then(
```

to

```
dispatch(updateValuesRouting(values, routingID)).then(...)
```

BTW, you missed `Promise.reject()` in `catch` block.

Hope this will help!

Comment: you are right, I missed the syntax in how to call back to the method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you return a promise it would be on the dispatch call not on the action. Like this

```
 dispatch(updateValuesRouting(values, routingID)).then(/*put some other code here*/))
```

Not on the action itself

```
  dispatch(updateValuesRouting(values, routingID)).then()) // Gives an error
```